# I want to do group_concat in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, string-aggregation

I know `group_concat` doesn't work in SQL Server 2008, but I want to do `group_concat`.

My sample data looks like this:

```
email address         | product code   
----------------------+---------------
garry123@gmail.com    | A123A  
garry123@gmail.com    | AB263    
ada121@hotmail.com    | 45632A   
ada121@hotmail.com    | 78YU
garry123@gmail.com    | 6543D
```

and I want this result:

```
garry123@gmail.com | A123A,AB263,6543D 
ada121@hotmail.com | 45632A,78YU
```

Code I have tried:

```
SELECT
    c.EmailAddress,
    od.concat(productcode) as Product_SKU
FROM
    OrderDetails od
JOIN 
    Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
JOIN 
    Customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE
    o.OrderDate BETWEEN 01/01/2016 AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY 
    c.EmailAddress
```

I get an error:

> Cannot find either column "od" or the user-defined function or  aggregate "od.concat", or the name is ambiguous.

But this is not working. Can anyone please tell me correct way of doing this?

Code I am trying after editing:

```
SELECT
    c.EmailAddress,
    productcode = STUFF((SELECT ',' + od.productcode
                         FROM Orderdetails od
                         WHERE c.EmailAddress = od.EmailAddress
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    OrderDetails od
JOIN 
    Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
JOIN 
    Customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE
    o.OrderDate BETWEEN 01/01/2016 AND GETDATE()
```

Now I'm getting this error:

> Invalid column name 'EmailAddress'.

Comment: look out this answers :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @TheGameiswar..I looked into solution but how will i apply that to my problem? what is table_name,column_name in that solution?? and i have 3 tables to join. I would appreciate if you can help me more

Comment: use cte on top of your final output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you an illustration of joining (in this case a self join, but all joins work) and using STUFF for this.  Notice the WHERE clause inside the STUFF.  This is what links the record to the correct values.

```
declare @test table
(
email varchar(50),
address varchar(50)
)

insert into @test VALUES
('garry123@gmail.com','A123A'),  
('garry123@gmail.com','AB263'),   
('ada121@hotmail.com','45632A'),   
('ada121@hotmail.com','78YU'),
('garry123@gmail.com','6543D')

SELECT DISTINCT 
       email,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + address  
              FROM   @test t2 
              WHERE  t2.email  = t1.email  
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') Address
FROM   @test t1
```

Edit

OK so what you want (what you really, really want) is:

```
declare @customers table
(
emailaddress varchar(50),
customerid int
)

insert into @customers VALUES
('garry123@gmail.com',1),  
('ada121@hotmail.com',2)   

declare @orders table
(
orderid int,
customerid int,
orderdate date
)

insert into @orders VALUES
(1, 1, '2017-06-02'),
(2, 1, '2017-06-05'),
(3, 1, '2017-07-13'),
(4, 2, '2017-06-13')

declare @orderdetails table
(
id int,
orderid int,
productcode varchar(10)
)

insert into @orderdetails VALUES
(1, 1, 'apple pie'),
(2, 1, 'bread'),
(3, 2, 'custard'),
(4, 2, 'orange'),
(5, 3, 'orange'),
(6, 4, 'orange')

SELECT DISTINCT c.EmailAddress, productcode=
STUFF((SELECT ',' + odc.productcode FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT emailaddress,productcode FROM 
@orders o2 inner join @orderdetails od2 on
o2.orderid = od2.orderid
inner join @customers c2 ON c2.customerid = o2.customerid) odc 
WHERE odc.emailaddress=c.emailaddress 
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM @OrderDetails od 
JOIN @Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
JOIN @Customers c ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID 
WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND getdate()
```

Notice the change here.  The SELECT in the STUFF is now from a sub-query, so that you can group by EmailAddress.

Additional explanation

Your aim is to have a concatenation of product codes grouped by customer (represented by email address). The problem is that product codes are in the orderdetails table and emailaddress is in the customer table, but there is no field which links the two. The customer table has a one to many relationship with the orders table and the orders table has a one to many relationship with the orderdetails table. That is one level of abstraction too many. So we need to give the database a helping hand by providing a direct link between productcode and emailaddress. This we do via the Sub-query. I hope that this makes it clearer for you.

Comment: I am trying this way:SELECT
 c.EmailAddress,
productcode=STUFF((SELECT ',' + od.productcode
FROM Orderdetails od
WHERE
c.EmailAddress=od.EmailAddress
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
        FROM
            OrderDetails od
        JOIN Orders o
         ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID 
    JOIN Customers c
    ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
    WHERE
    o.OrderDate BETWEEN 01/01/2016 AND getdate() but getting error message

Comment: ...If you can please help getting my code corrected

Comment: Please edit your question with the new attempt and tell us the error.

Comment: Is EmailAddress in OrderDetails?

Comment: no it is in customers table. and product code is in order details table

Comment: Then you need WHERE od.OrderID = o.OrderID (not EmailAddress)

Comment: ..it passed that error but query is still not running and giving opening recordset and nothing is happening..can you please check if i need everything in last from clause?

Comment: Try BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND

Comment: ..It is working but not giving right results. In my results i have 1000 of email addresses and let's say gary123@gmail.com bought 2 products in june and then again 4 products in july. so the result is not grouping two months product together. It is showing them separately. Is there a way to group them?

Comment: See my edit - I revised my answer to group orders together by customer

Comment: ..Thanku so much..It is working the way i want..but can you explain me in detail why another select is needed?

Comment: ..Thanku so much...:)